# iPhone calendar and time zones (EventKit)

Tags: iphone, ios4, calendar, xamarin.ios, eventkit

The time zone handling on the iPhone seems a little confusing to me.  As far as adding a new EKEvent to the device calendar it looks like you always just set the start/end times in local time, there is no timezone or offset we need to work with.  Is this true?

I assume the device knows the time zone at the time the entry is made.  The confusion comes in when you look at the device's Settings/Mail, Contacts, Calendars and scroll to the bottom for the time zone data.  Whether to have time zone support ON/OFF, a set time zone, etc.

So if I am in California and add an event to the device and the time zone is set to "New York" and time zone support is ON, what time will the EKEvent actually show in?

Has anyone dealt with the iOS calendar via EventKit and have lessons to learn regarding time zone handling?  Or is it straight-forward, just use the local time and enter the event and the device will take care of the rest?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[NSDate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) don't have a timezone, they're in UTC (AFAIK). If you need to convert from/to a certain timezone, use [NSCalendar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html%23//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSCalendar). I suppose Mail and friends need explicit timezone handling for dates coming from external sources.